# Knockout.js Mixed with Server Side Template Engine Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: knockout.js, twirl

I am using Knockoutjs for the client side and a server-side template engine(namely Twirl).
The code that I am working on looks something like the following(*simplified)

```
<div id="outer">
  @if(some condition) {
    <ul class="type-a">
      <li>item1</li>
      :
  } else {
    <ul class="type-b">
     <li>item2</li>
      :
  }
  @if(another condition) {
    <-- ko if: isAlwaysFalse -->
      <li>item3</li>
    <-- /ko -->
  }
  <-- ko if: isAlwaysFalse -->
    <li>item4</li>
  <-- /ko -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do with this is to remove(hide) the `item3` and `item4` from its parent(the `ul` element), but the rendered HTML ends up like below assuming that `some condition === true` and `another condition === true`.

```
<div id="outer">
  <ul class="type-a">
    <-- ko if: isAlwaysFalse -->
    <-- /ko -->
    <-- ko if: isAlwaysFalse -->
    <-- /ko -->
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why do the knockout's if conditions not take effect and get moved up to just below the parent element `ul`?

Comment: Knockout is a templating engine. What's the point of employing *yet another* templating engine on the server side? Doesn't that make things more complicated than they need to be?

Comment: It is there, so I need to work on it. No other options.

Comment: That's a bit... thin. What does "no other options" mean when the question is "does this even make sense"? What does the server-side templating engine do that knockout cannot?

Comment: How can I make this work using both `Knockout.js` and `Twirl`?. Hope you understand my question correctly

Comment: I understand your question. Do you understand mine?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add correct knockout js virtual element syntax.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

Comment: The upper code sample in the OP's post shows the correct usage.

Comment: I am using [containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element), which I think is valid syntax.

Comment: <!-- ko you have missed ! char. in your sample <-- ko missing ! char.

Comment: And you could replace your serve side if statements with knockout if binding here. But you could mix both if you are really required to do so.